# Add file node to tree based on it's path

Tags: c#, algorithm, tree, filetree

I have the struct:

```
public struct BaseFile
{
    public string FileName;
    public string Path; // this is not the full path. it is the fullPath of it's parent directory in other words.
}
```

and I have the class

```
 public class MyFileDir // can be a file or directory
 {
      public string Name;
      public string FullPath;
      public List<MyFileDir> Children;
      public bool IsDirectory;
      // many more other properties
 }
```

So I have one thread place files on `LinkedList<BaseFile> myLinkedList`   and I will like another thread to start casting those files too `MyFileDir root` (note I used linkedList instead of list because the addresses of linkedList does not change where a List changes its address every time it needs to grow)

I have a bool variable IsRunning that will let me know if the other thread is still adding base files to the linked list. So I have something like:

```
        var curNode = myLinkedList.First;

        while (IsRunning)
        {
            if (curNode.Next == null) // wait until next node is not null
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                continue;
            }

            curNode = curNode.Next;
            AddItemToTree(curNode.Value);
        }
```

so as you can see I am having trouble implementing the method `AddItemToTree` I basically will like to start building the tree in that method. So first I will look at the root and search the directory where I should add `curNode.Value`. I am having a hard time doing that.

Comment: sleep(0) would be better since it just gives up the current time slot. Rather then wait for 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     MyFileDir root = new MyFileDir(); //root Node
```

&

```
     var curNode = myLinkedList.First;

    while (IsRunning)
    {
        if (curNode.Next == null) // wait until next node is not null
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            continue;
        }

        curNode = curNode.Next;
        curFileDir = new MyFileDir(curNode);// your cast here


    List<string> mylist = curFileDir.FullPath.Split(new string[] { @"\" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList(); // this gives a list of dirs in FullPath to explore



        MyFileDir temp = root;
        foreach (string filedirName in mylist)
        {
            temp = AddNode(temp, filedirName );
        }


  }
```

the first loop means if the node exists return it, else create it & return it

```
       private MyFileDir AddNode(MyFileDir parent, string filedirName)
{
    foreach (MyFileDir subfiledir in parent.Children)
        if (subfiledir.Name == header)
            return subfiledir;

    MyFileDir filedir = new MyFileDir(fileName);
    parent.Children.Add(fileName);
    return fileName;
}
```